# Wrap content in DIV

Tags: jquery

simple question i think, but cant figure this out

How can I wrap particular text into DIV?

Have this
`Price:<strong>£12.30 (Ex VAT)</strong>`

And need to have this:

```
<div>Price:<strong>£12.30 (Ex VAT)</strong></div>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why are you doing this with Javascript? You should be generating the correct markup with a server-side language.

Comment: For a more reliable method it might help to post *all* your html because the technique will differ depending on how you have everything marked up, because you'll have to target a text node sibling and an element node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use appendChild method :

```
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');

newDiv.innerHTML = "Price:<strong>£12.30 (Ex VAT)</strong>";

document.getElementById('parentDiv').appendChild(newDiv);
```

Here is the [JQuery equvalent](http://docs.jquery.com/API/1.1/Core#.24.28_html_.29) of the code above :

```
var newDiv = $("<div>Price:<strong>£12.30 (Ex VAT)</strong></div>");
$('#parentElement').append(newDiv);
```

Or :

```
$("<div>Price:<strong>£12.30 (Ex VAT)</strong></div>").appendTo("#parentElement");
```

Comment: Looking for jQuery method please?

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'Price:<strong>£12.30 (Ex VAT)</strong>';
var div = $('<div />').html(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a [wrap](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrap) function that does exactly what you are describing...

```
 var str = "Price: <strong>£12.30 (Ex VAT)</strong>";

 $(str).wrap("<div></div>").appendTo("body");
```